# How can add resources like images to source control under Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

Xcode 4 does not automatically add images to the source control (git), also option to add files to source control is disabled in the context menu when I select an image.

Is there something I am doing wrong or will I need to add those files to the repository by some other means.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like only way to add those files is from command line via git then Xcode tracks them properly. And I just did that and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4 doesn't seem to add any files to the GIT at all with the project navigator "Add files to ..." command, this seems ridiculous.

To demonstrate the problem, simply create an iOS project of any type.  Copy a folder of source code into main project folder and then right click the project and select Add Files to .  No matter what you select when adding the folder (group/folder) Xcode doesn't add them to the git.

Creating new files within Xcode does add them to the git of course.

Help anyone?